# Is it safe to override a Category-defined method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I have a class structure of the type `UIViewControllerSubclass : UIViewController`, where the only function of UIViewControllerSubclass is to `#import UIViewController+Category.h`. The reason I added methods in a category is so that I can also make `UITableViewControllerSubclass : UITableViewController`, which will `#import UIViewController+Category.h` as well. As we all know, don't repeat yourself.

Now assume that UIViewController+Category.h has the structure:

```
@interface UIViewController(Category)
- (void) method1;
- (void) method2;
@end
```

How safe is it to create `UIViewControllerSubclassSubclass : UIViewControllerSubclass`, which will override `method1`? I assume this will work because of Objective-C's message passing, but for some reason my intuition is telling me that I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to remember that Objective-C is "duck typed".  If a class supports a method you can (safely) invoke it, even if the method is not defined in the class's .h file.  (How you sneak past the compiler checks is up to you.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything should work fine since the category is applied to `UIViewController`, so all instances of `UIViewController`, including subclasses, will have access to the methods.  There's nothing unsafe about it; that's how categories are intended to be applied.

Comment: I suppose it just "feels" unsafe because the category method isn't as tightly coupled to the class as an instance method.